# Unexpected token when deserializing object in JsonConvert.DeserializeObject

Tags: c#, json.net

I have the following test code:

```
[TestClass]
public class TestJsonDeserialize
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        [JsonProperty("myint")]
        public int MyInt { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("Mybool")]
        public bool Mybool { get; set; }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test1()
    {
        var errors = new List<string>();
        var json1 = "{\"myint\":1554860000,\"Mybool\":false}";
        var json2 = "{\"myint\":3554860000,\"Mybool\":false}";
        var i = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(json2, new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            Error = delegate (object sender, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.ErrorEventArgs args)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(args.ErrorContext.Error.Message);
                errors.Add(args.ErrorContext.Error.Message);
                args.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
            }
        });
        Assert.IsTrue(errors.Count <= 1);
    }
}
```

The call to JsonConvert.DeserializeObject produces 2 errors. One of them is expected, but the other not.
The errors are:

- JSON integer 3554860000 is too large or small for an Int32. Path 'myint', line 1, position 19.
- Unexpected token when deserializing object: Boolean. Path 'Mybool', line 1, position 34.

Why is there a 2nd error although the 1st error is marked as handled.
I already updated from Newtonsoft.Json 8.0.2 to 9.0.1 but it remains.
When passing the first string (json1 instead of json2), then no errors at all occur.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**

Reported as [Issue 1194: *JsonTextReader.ParseNumber leads to error after ThrowReaderError*](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1194) and closed by Newtonsoft as not reproducible in then-current build which subsequently was released as [Json.NET 10.0.1](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/10.0.1).

**Original Answer**

This may be a bug in [`JsonTextReader`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonTextReader.cs).

In [`JsonTextReader.ParseNumber(ReadType readType, char firstChar, int initialPosition)`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonTextReader.cs#L1879) there is the following logic, somewhat simplified:

```
else if (readType == ReadType.ReadAsInt32)
{

// Snip

        int value;
        ParseResult parseResult = ConvertUtils.Int32TryParse(_stringReference.Chars, _stringReference.StartIndex, _stringReference.Length, out value);
        if (parseResult == ParseResult.Success)
        {
            numberValue = value;
        }
        else if (parseResult == ParseResult.Overflow)
        {
            throw ThrowReaderError("JSON integer {0} is too large or small for an Int32.".FormatWith(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, _stringReference.ToString()));
        }
        else
        {
            throw ThrowReaderError("Input string '{0}' is not a valid integer.".FormatWith(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, _stringReference.ToString()));
        }
    }

    numberType = JsonToken.Integer;
}

// Snip
// Finally, after successfully parsing the number

ClearRecentString();

// index has already been updated
SetToken(numberType, numberValue, false);
```

At the point the exception is thrown by `ThrowReadError()`, the stream position has been advanced past the too-large integer.  However, the value for [`JsonReader.TokenType`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader_TokenType.htm) has not been updated and still returns [`JsonToken.PropertyName`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonToken.htm) for the last token that was successfully parsed, namely the `"myint"` name.  Later, after the exception is swallowed and ignored, the inconsistency between the stream position and current token value causes the `"Mybool"` property name to be skipped, leading to the second error.

If, in the debugger, when the exception is thrown I manually call

```
SetToken(JsonToken.Undefined);
ClearRecentString();
```

Then the remainder of the file can be successfully parsed.  (I'm not sure `JsonToken.Undefined` is the right choice here.)

You might want to [report an issue](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues) to Newtonsoft.

Since the `JsonReader` is not passed in to the error handler, the only **workaround** I could find is to subclass `JsonTextReader` as follows:

```
public class FixedJsonTextReader : JsonTextReader
{
    public FixedJsonTextReader(TextReader reader) : base(reader) { }

    public override int? ReadAsInt32()
    {
        try
        {
            return base.ReadAsInt32();
        }
        catch (JsonReaderException)
        {
            if (TokenType == JsonToken.PropertyName)
                SetToken(JsonToken.None);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

And then do:

```
var errors = new List<string>();
var json2 = "{\"myint\":3554860000,\"Mybool\":false}";

using (var reader = new FixedJsonTextReader(new StringReader(json2)))
{
    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        Error = delegate(object sender, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.ErrorEventArgs args)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(args.ErrorContext.Error.Message);
            errors.Add(args.ErrorContext.Error.Message);
            args.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
        }
    };
    var i = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(settings).Deserialize<MyClass>(reader);
}
Assert.IsTrue(errors.Count <= 1); // Passes
```

Comment: The workouround works for my test project. Thanks a lot. I now reported an issue on github as you suggested.